# Write an algorithm to set values to zero in a matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I came across a question

> Write an algorithm such that if an element in an MxN matrix is 0, its entire row and column are set to 0.

I am new to java so my code might not look good. Please feel free to suggest to me how to make it better and optimized.

What I'm seeing on the output is this:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Instead of:

```
0 0 0 0 
1 0 3 4
```

And this is the code I'm using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows=2, cols=4; 
    int[][] arr = { {1,0,2,3}, {1,2,3,4} };
    print(arr, rows, cols);
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            if(arr[i][j] == 0){
                for(int t1=0; t1<cols; t1++){
                    arr[i][t1]=0;
                }
                for(int t1=0; t1<rows; t1++){
                    arr[t1][j]=0;
                }
            }
            print(arr, rows,cols);
        }
    }
}
private static void print(int[][]arr, int rows, int cols) {
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
                System.out.println("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
}
```

I haven't been able to determine the error in my logic.  Can someone help me spot what's wrong?

Comment: Since your code works you this might be a better fit on Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange which is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code. We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.

Comment: First thing is first, make a method which takes an array and returns the result (although this is a question to clarify with the interviewer -- do they want you to modify the original array, or is returning a new one alright?). When they ask something like this, they want to see your approach, and they will likely suggest you optimize it. For example, your algorithm idea would be O(n^3), and I expect there is a nice O(n^2) solution.

Comment: No, I think your code doesn't work correct. If cell at (0,0) is 0 your code will create a matrix - step by step- that ends in a matrix with all cells are 0. Right? So this isn't a question of codereview or refactoring. It's a question of, why does the algorithm not work correct. ;-)

Comment: Did you even test this code? *"I wrote the algorithm which works fine"* - what is your definition of "works fine"? The example Matrix clearly creates the wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

The root of your problem is that you're writing to the same array that you're reading from.

The initial `0` entry at `[0][1]` zeroes out the rest of that row and the `[1][1]` element below in the next row.  Because you replace the values in-line, your subsequent checks on the outer loops will fire as true which causes the entire array to be zeroed out.

Specifically, the problem is at the third line from this snippet:

```
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
        if(arr[i][j] == 0){  // problem is here
```

After you process the first zero at the `[0][1]` element, you have an array that looks like:

```
0 0 0 0
1 0 3 4
```

That `if(arr[i][j] == 0)` check will then fire at `[0][2]` and `[0][3]` which will result in:

```
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

And when you get to the `[1][1]` element, the rest of the second row is zeroed out.

---

A hackish but easy way to fix the problem is to simply declare a second array identical to the first and then make the updates to the second array.

```
int[][] arr2 = { {1,0,2,3}, {1,2,3,4} };
...
    for(int t1=0; t1<cols; t1++){
        arr2[i][t1]=0;
    }
    for(int t1=0; t1<rows; t1++){
         arr2[t1][j]=0;
    }
```